# Filling a std string with memcpy does not set length

Tags: c++, curl

I have the following code to fill a `std::string` with a curl get response.

```
struct curl_string {
    std::string tmpStr;
    size_t len;
};

void init_string(struct curl_string *s) {
    s->len = 0;
}

size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct curl_string *s)
{
    size_t new_len = s->len + size*nmemb;
    s->tmpStr.reserve(new_len + 1);

    memcpy(&s->tmpStr[0] + s->len, ptr, size*nmemb);
    s->tmpStr[new_len] = '\0';
    s->len = new_len;

    return size*nmemb;
}
```

The problem is, even though I reserve the correct length, when I try to read back the string, the size is still 0.

I wanted to avoid using a for loop to add 1 character at a time. Is there a way to do this but still have the correct string length in the `std::string` ?

Comment: Why do you need the separate `len` member? You can use [`std::string::capacity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity) to get the number of characters you have [reserved](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) space for.

Comment: Also, why are you using `memcpy` to copy the string? It seems that `ptr` already is a `char` pointer, so just cast it in a normal assignment. And you shouldn't really manually terminate `std::string` objects. In fact, in your case you could do it all in a simple one-liner: `s->tmpStr = std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr), nmemb);`

Comment: memcpy is used because it is a binary buffer of fixed length, not a null terminated string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `std::string::reserve` just reserves the memory for the extra characters, but doesn't actually alter the length of the string. The size isn't recalculated when the underlying buffer is modified, because this would be near-impossible to detect in all cases.

The solution is to just use `resize` instead of `reserve`:

```
s->tmpStr.resize(new_len + 1);
```

Is there a reason for keeping track of the length manually? You can just call `s->tmpStr.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

To add legacy string into std::string, you can use 3 types of member-functions.

If you want to replace, `assign` is better:

```
std::string str = "old text";
str.assign("new text", 8); // you can eliminate length
// str become "new text"
```

If you want to insert end of the string, `append` is better:

```
std::string str = "old text";
str.append(" new text", 9); // you can eliminate length
// str become "old text new text"
```

By the way,
if your data might contain binary,
I recommend `std::vector<char>` rather than `std::string`.